# Finding the sum of $1+4k+9k^2+...+n^2k^{n-1}$

Tags: summation

I'm having trouble using Abel's summation formula as $a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n=(a_1-a_2)(b_1)+(a_2-a_3)(b_1+b_2)+...+(a_{n-1}-a_n)(b_1+b_2+...+b_{n-1})+a_n(b_1+b_2+...+b_n)$

to find the sum of $1+4k+9k^2+...+n^2k^{n-1}$.

I know $1+2k+3k^2+...+nk^{n-1}=\frac{nk^n}{k-1}-\frac{k^n-1}{(k-1)^2}$ from a previous part.

Applying Abel's formula once I get $(-3)(1)+(-5)(1+k)+...-(2n-1)(1+k+k^2+...+k^{n-2})+n^2(1+k+k^2+...+k^{n-1})$

Then I think the next step is to apply it again to get $-2(1)-2(1+1+k)-...-2(1+(1+k)+(1+k+k^2)+...+(1+k+k^2+...+k^{n-3}))+(2n-1)(1+(1+k)+...+(1+k+...+k^{n-2}))+n^2\left(\frac{k^n-1}{k-1}\right)$

$=-2[1+(1+1+k)+(1+1+k+1+k+k^2)+...+(1+(1+k)+...+(1+k+..+k^{n-3}))]+(2n-1)((n-1)+(n-2)k+...+(n-(n-1))k^{n-2})+n^2\left(\frac{k^n-1}{k-1}\right)$

$=-2[1+(1+1+k)+(1+1+k+1+k+k^2)+...+(1+(1+k)+...+(1+k+..+k^{n-3}))]+(2n-1)\left(n\left(\frac{k^{n-1}-1}{k-1}\right)-\frac{(n-1)k^{n-1}}{k-1}+\frac{k^{n-1}-1}{(k-1)^2}\right)+n^2\left(\frac{k^n-1}{k-1}\right)$

$=-2[1+(1+1+k)+(1+1+k+1+k+k^2)+...+(1+(1+k)+...+(1+k+..+k^{n-3}))]+(2n-1)\left(\frac{k^{n-1}-n}{k-1}+\frac{k^{n-1}-1}{(k-1)^2}\right)+n^2\left(\frac{k^n-1}{k-1}\right)$

$=-2[1+(1+1+k)+(1+1+k+1+k+k^2)+...+(1+(1+k)+...+(1+k+..+k^{n-3}))]+\frac{2n-1}{(k-1)^2}\left(k^n-nk+n-1\right)+n^2\left(\frac{k^n-1}{k-1}\right)$

My problem arises when trying to find $[1+(1+1+k)+(1+1+k+1+k+k^2)+...+(1+(1+k)+...+(1+k+..+k^{n-3}))]$, it feels way too contrived and the sums within a sum thing is confusing me, I feel like I'm not taking the right approach, if anyone has a faster way using this formula that would be greatly appreciated.

By the way the solution is $\frac{n^2k^n}{k-1}-\frac{(2n-1)k^n+1}{(k-1)^2}+\frac{2k^n-2}{(k-1)^3}$

Comment: See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%5E2+z%5E%28n-1%29

Comment: @lhf, I know the answer, it is given to me in the answers. I'm asking how to actually do it using Abel's summation formula and not the infinite sum case, just up to $n$ terms. If you know how it would be great to know

Comment: not Abel summation, but if you treat $k$ as a real variable then just multiply your previous result by $k$ and then differentiate by $k$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

In one hand,
$$S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^nkx^k=x\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^nx^k.$$

Finally,
$$\text{Your sum}=\frac{d}{dx}S_n(x).$$

Answer (score 1):

Surb’s method is much cleaner, but you can also use the method used to find the sum of geometric series to solve this.

\begin{align}
v &= \sum_{k=1}^nk^2x^{k-1} \\
v-vx &= -n^2x^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k+1)x^k \\
&= -n^2x^n+2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}kx^k+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k
\end{align}

At which point solving for $v$ should be pretty easy (the same method can solve $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}kx^k$ if you want to use it).